# Kubernetes. Is it possible to configure a default namespace for a user?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to configure a default namespace (other than "default") for a user in kubernetes?

Thank you.

Comment: You can do it with `kubens` from https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, just set `.contexts[].context.namespace` in the kubeconfig file of the user.

You can do that manually with a text editor (`~/.kube/config`):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
...
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: frontend
    user: developer
  name: dev-frontend
current-context: dev-frontend
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
...
```

Or with `kubectl config`. This example sets the namespace to `frontend` in the current context:

```
kubectl config set "contexts."`kubectl config current-context`".namespace" frontend
```

For more details and explanation see this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

Answer (score 9):

Set namespace to current-context with:
`kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=my-namespace` or
`kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=<namespace>`

Check whether it is set or not with:
`kubectl config view | grep namespace:`

ref:[kubectl cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)